# why the external link dose not work on my wordpress site

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

in my site, when I use external link it's not work until I check it browse in the new tab; 
in other word it's not open in the same window;

like AA and BB menu in my site: 
http://home.masostudio.com/

whats the matter with this error?

Comment: `BB` doesn't work because it doesn't have an `href` attribute that points to a URL. How are you building the menu/links?

Comment: word press menu generator make links ; but the links divide by # sign; also it work on all browser but not in chrome

Comment: Chrome isn't the issue if this is the [menu generator](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide) you're talking about. It's all server side code and the built in menu builder isn't going to care what browser your on, it's generating markup. You might have something else going on. That's effecting that. It's hard to help as you're very thin on details and code.